# Mockk Missing calls inside every { ... } block

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, mockk

I'm stuck trying to mock some stuff with mockk:

I have the following setup on gradle

```
root:
  |-- App (just a sample app for the SDK)
  |-- SDK (SDK we develop) << apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
       |-- SDKimpl.kt
  |-- Foo (wrapper around a .jar library) << apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
       |-- Foo.kt
```

So I'm writing an `androidTest` for the SDK and trying to mock `Foo.kt`.
There's nothing unusual about Foo class, just direct `class Foo(private val someParams) {`

So using `androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.8.13"` the mock goes:

```
val mock: Foo = mockk()
// val mock: Foo = mockkClass(Foo::class) // also tried this
every { mock.getData() } returns listOf("1", "2", "3")
```

I'm always getting the following crash:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.checkMissingCalls(StubbingState.kt:14)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.recordingDone(StubbingState.kt:8)
at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:42)
```

Also tried just to gather information:

- running inside JVM test folder. It gets mocked without issues, but I can't run my test as JVM
- running `androidTest` inside `Foo` module. Got the same crash
- using mockkClass(Foo::class). Got some crash
- using annotation `@MockK` and `MockKAnnotations.init(this)`. Got some crash.
- added `Log.d` before `every {` line and inside `getData()` method and it seems the actual real method from the class is getting called during the mock setup. That seems super weird to me.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

**edit:**

as requested, full code. I'm current working on an isolated project to try to isolate the error, so Foo is just:

```
class Foo {

    fun getData(): String {
        Log.d(TAG, "invoked foo.getData()")
        return "trolololo"
    }

}
```

and then I have FooTest in `androidTest`:

```
class FooTest {

    @Test
    fun mock_foo() {
        val foo = mockk<Foo>()
        every { foo.getData() } returns "zero"
        assertEquals("zero", foo.getData())
    }

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems to be a Mockk opened issue: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/182

2 possible quick fixes (**pick one**):

1. Run the Instrumented Tests in an emulator >= Android-P
2. Set `Foo` class as open (and the method(s) you want to mock too)

Answer (score 20):

Try to check the [official guide](https://mockk.io/#object-mocks) and see what is missing.

In my case, I tried to mock an extension in Kotlin but missed the `mockkStatic`

```
fun Date.asMyTime() : DateTime = DateTime(this, DateTimeZone.getDefault())

mockkStatic("packageName.FileNameKt") // This is what I was missing
every {
    DateTime().asMyTime()
} returns mock(DateTime::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks for `mockkStatic("packageName.FileNameKt")` when test extension method! Did you mean `mockk`, not `mock` in the last line?

Comment: Instead of `mockkStatic("packageName.FileNameKt")` you can write: `mockkStatic(FileName::class.java.name + "Kt")`.

Answer (score 19):

In my case I forgot to `spyk` the class I was applying `every {...}` to.

```
val presenter = spyk(MyPresenter())

every { view.myFun(any()) } returns Unit
```

Comment: Can we add `any()` to `spyk`

Comment: @AkshayHazari `spyk` is used to add mocking and verification abilities to "real" objects.  Anything that can be done with `mockk`s can be done on `spyk`'d objects, such as `every{}`, `verify{}` etc.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I've missed

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case I tried to mock using mock() function instead mock**k**() (double k)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the object is really a mock, not the real object.

For instance:

```
- Sdk sdk = Sdk()
+ Sdk sdk = mockk()
  every { sdk.crypto } returns mockk()
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I used a java class without getters

```
public class KeyStorePasswordPair {
    public KeyStore keyStore;
    public String keyPassword;

    public KeyStorePasswordPair(KeyStore keyStore, String keyPassword) {
        this.keyStore = keyStore;
        this.keyPassword = keyPassword;
    }
}
```

I needed to add getters for the variables to make mockking work:

```
public class KeyStorePasswordPair {
    public KeyStore getKeyStore() {
        return keyStore;
    }

    public String getKeyPassword() {
        return keyPassword;
    }

    private KeyStore keyStore;
    private String keyPassword;

    public KeyStorePasswordPair(KeyStore keyStore, String keyPassword) {
        this.keyStore = keyStore;
        this.keyPassword = keyPassword;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Mockk Missing calls inside every { ... } block

may also be thrown when you have an `every` block defined on an object that is not a mockk, for example:

You define stub behavior like this

```
every { foo.getData() } returns DATA
```

and then try to:

```
every { DATA.getVersion() } returns VERSION
```

Where `DATA` and `VERSION` objects are declared (and instantiated) in the test class.

The error message is not very informative and a bit misleading in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If the method or attribute that you want to mock inside the every block is final, then that's the reason.

Answer (score -6):

try like this

```
`when`(mock.getData()).thenReturn(listOf("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: `when` is not a function of Mockk

Comment: @DouglasMesquita, agree, it is Mockito.